# Magento 2 get Allowed Countries by store config value?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

for example 4 store in a website. StoreId=3,how can getting this store Allowed Countries?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can refer my answer as mention below link.

[**https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363605/magento-2-get-allowed-countries-list-by-store-code/363608#363608**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363605/magento-2-get-allowed-countries-list-by-store-code/363608#363608)

Let me know if you have any query.